# Optional property wrapper used in Codable struct fails when value is missing

Tags: swift

I've got a `struct` with a `Double` property that is represented as a `String` in the `JSON` coming from the backend.

```
struct Test: Codable {
    @StringRepresentation
    var value: Double?
}
```

Instead of implement `init(from:)` I've created the following property wrapper that takes advantage of `LosslessStringConvertible` to convert to and from `String`

```
@propertyWrapper
struct StringRepresentation<T: LosslessStringConvertible> {
    private var value: T?

    var wrappedValue: T? {
        get {
            return value
        }
        set {
            value = newValue
        }
    }
}

extension StringRepresentation: Codable {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if container.decodeNil() {
            value = nil
        } else {
            let string = try container.decode(String.self)
            value = T(string)
        }
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        if let value = value {
            try container.encode("\(value)")
        } else {
            try container.encodeNil()
        }
    }
}
```

This works for

```
{
  "value": "12.0"
}
```

and

```
{
  "value": null
}
```

but fails when the property is missing

```
{
}
```

giving the error

```
▿ DecodingError
  ▿ keyNotFound : 2 elements
    - .0 : CodingKeys(stringValue: "value", intValue: nil)
    ▿ .1 : Context
      - codingPath : 0 elements
      - debugDescription : "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"value\", intValue: nil) (\"value\")."
      - underlyingError : nil
```

I'm guessing this happens because the underlying `StringRepresentation` is not Optional.
How can I make it optional?

Edit:
Also, I have to encode the object as

```
{
"value": null
}
```

i.e the value can't be omitted.

Comment: how about if you take value as String and after that convert to Double as per your need? this way you done need to you StringRepresentation.

Comment: Yes, of course, I could do that. But I want to keep the property as Double so I don’t have to change any other code except here. I also don’t want to have to implement the init.

Comment: okay, let me try that way.

Comment: How about just adding an internal variable called `_value` for example and then decoding the value as a String in there and then have the actual Double value be a computed property from it?

Comment: There are of course multiple ways of solving this, but I’m interested in using property wrappers for this and for other similar issues in the future.

Comment: @LescaiIonel did you ever find a solution to this? I have the exact some problem that I'm wrestling with

Answer (score 17):

Use an extension on KeyedDecodingContainer and add an overload for decode method like this:

```
extension KeyedDecodingContainer {

    func decode<T>(_ type: StringRepresentation <T?>.Type, forKey key: Self.Key) throws -> StringRepresentation <T?> where T : Decodable {
        return try decodeIfPresent(type, forKey: key) ?? StringRepresentation <T?>(wrappedValue: nil)
    }
}
```

This will make sure that your synthesised property `_value` which is a non-optional is always created but in case the key is not present in json it only wraps around a nil value.

This works with synthesised Codable initialiser as this overloaded `decode` is used instead of its generic counterpart because it has a concrete type which is preferred over a generic one if present.

Comment: I did this as well. Do not forget to add a `init(wrappedValue: T?)` to your wrapper.

Comment: @huwr how do you write init() code? ` init(wrappedValue: T?) {
    self.wrappedValue = wrappedValue
  }` like this?

Comment: @huwr I don't think you need `init(wrappedValue: T?)`, because in these cases the type of `StringRepresentation`'s value is already optional.

Comment: not getting called for my type and I think one of the reasons might be that there is no function like this to overload where you can change the generic T into optional T ie T? . Here is the list of all function from apple documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/keyeddecodingcontainer

and you can't change decode<T> into decode<T?> as well.  and can not pass nill into generic type T

one option is to pass default value instead of nill that will also help in cleaner code where you have to only check for default value instead of both nill and defalut.